# Java регулярные выражения, найти буквы из которых можно составить слово

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка в которой нужно найти буквы из которых можно составить определенное слово, т.е. каждая буква должна появится хотя бы один раз.

К примеру: `String s="  oasd  c ";`

Регулярное выражение к ней `

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("c+ & o+");



    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(toReturn);


    return matcher.find();`
```

Не работает, должно выдать true но выдает false Как написать выражение которое проверит строку где каждая буква которая будет указана встретиться один или несколько раз. Пробовал по разному, долбился час.

Comment: Что это за регулярка такая? она будет соответствовать напримет строке `cccccccccccccccc & ooooo`, но никак не той, что в примере у вас. Вы хотите регуляркой найти буквы `c` и `o` в примере? Амперсанд не является спецсимволом в регулярном выражении. Вероятно, вы хотите что-то вроде `.*c.*|.*o.*`

Comment: Я знаю что этого символа нет в регулярных выражениях, я обозначил что бы я хотел получить, но я не знаю как это написать, ваш код неверный, потому что с ИЛИ о, а если какой либо из этих букв не будет, слово уже не составить.

Comment: А вам обязательно регуляркой надо? Что-то мне подсказывает, что вам придётся писать все возможно комбинации букв. Например для букв c и o - `(.*o.*c.*)|(.*c.*o.*)`

Comment: А иероглифы Вам не поискать? Из них тоже слова составляют. Китайские, японские там...

Comment: Любое слово? Или у вас есть заданное слово, которое надо составить (или словарь таких слов)?

Comment: Определенное слово, к примеру ДОМ, нужно проверить в строке чтобы каждый из этих символов встречался хотя бы один раз.

Comment: Значит дано две строки. Одну назовём СЛОВО, другую БУКВЫ. И надо проверить, что в строке БУКВЫ есть все буквы, которые есть в СЛОВЕ. И надо это сделать непременно регулярными выражениями. Так?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать Positive Lookahead. Например, для выражения

```
(?=.*м)(?=.*а)(?=.*р)(?=.*т)(.*)
```

и тестового набора

```
мама мыра раму
мама мыра ртаму
трам
тран
```

будут поматчены строки

```
мама мыра ртаму
трам
```